# API Request item.get by list host name

Tags: zabbix

want to returned values itemsid by list hostnames

found variant for hostid list

```
zabbix_get=\
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "hostids": [123, 234],
            "search": {
                "key_": "vfs.fs.size"
            },
            "sortfield": "name"
        },
        "auth": authToken.get("result"),
        "id": authToken.get("id")
    }
```

tried to request by one hostname - GOOD

```
zabbix_get=\
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "host": "server01"
            "search": {
                "key_": "vfs.fs.size"
            },
            "sortfield": "name"
        },
        "auth": authToken.get("result"),
        "id": authToken.get("id")
    }
```

Tried to request by list hostnames

```
zabbix_get=\
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "hosts": ["server01","server02"]
            "search": {
                "key_": "vfs.fs.size"
            },
            "sortfield": "name"
        },
        "auth": authToken.get("result"),
        "id": authToken.get("id")
    }
```

zabbix is frozen.

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [item.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/item/get) method does not support a parameter named `hosts`, so it is now trying to get you data for all of the hosts (and templates).

If you want to filter by multiple hosts, use the `hostids` parameter instead.